# PyQT - Cambiar entre ventanas con StackedWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

Dividí la aplicación en partes, pero por ahora sólo quiero que funcione cuando trato de cambiar entre ventanas (sin crear una nueva o cerrarla). Esto lo estoy haciendo con botones.

Abre bien sin problemas y empieza en el menu principal, y en el hay un botón que te lleva al segundo menu que es el "search menu"; Éste funciona bien. Entonces cuando estás en el search menu hay otro botón que te llevaría de nuevo al menu principal, pero no funciona.

Si no entienden lo que digo ejecuten el código y se va a entender todo.

```
import os, sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox, QStackedWidget
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        login_widget = LoginWidget(self)
        login_widget.button.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(login_widget)

        search_widget = searchWidget(self)
        search_widget.returnButton.clicked.connect(self.returning) #The returnButton from searchWidget(self) connects to the function returning(self), but the returning function does not return to the home menu.
        self.central_widget.addWidget(search_widget)
    def login(self):
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Login')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        logged_in_widget = searchWidget(self)
        search_widget = searchWidget(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(logged_in_widget) # This part is key
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(logged_in_widget)
    def returning(self):
      # Here what im doing is restoring everything like it was before in the home menu, that's why I put the "Login" button again (in line 31).
      # This is not very optimized but i put it all again so that its more understandable. I can also, instead of all this code (from line 30 to 37), put a call to the login function like this: login(self) but I prefer the first way.
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Login')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        logged_in_widget = searchWidget(self)
        search_widget = searchWidget(self)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(logged_in_widget)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(logged_in_widget)
      # So, i got the buttons there they look fine, but the return button doesn't do anything, while the "login" button (that switchs to the searchWidget) does work.



class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Login')
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('You are on the menu now')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        # you might want to do self.button.click.connect(self.parent().login) here

class searchWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(searchWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.returnButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Return')
        layout.addWidget(self.returnButton)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('logged in in searchwidget!!!!')
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que estás haciendo demasiado trabajo extra en tus métodos, este es el código que he hecho funcionar:

```
import os, sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox, QStackedWidget
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.central_widget = QtGui.QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        # Login
        self.login_widget = LoginWidget(self)
        self.login_widget.button.clicked.connect(self.login)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.login_widget)
        # Return
        self.search_widget = SearchWidget(self)
        self.search_widget.returnButton.clicked.connect(self.returning)
        self.central_widget.addWidget(self.search_widget)

    def login(self):
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.search_widget)

    def returning(self):
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.login_widget)


class LoginWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Login')
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('You are on the menu now')
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

class SearchWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SearchWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.returnButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Return')
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel('logged in in searchwidget!!!!')
        layout.addWidget(self.returnButton)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

### Notas:

- Observa como he definido `self.login_widget` y `self.search_widget` en el método `__init__` como atributos del `MainWindow` para ser usados posteriormente en sus respectivos métodos
- En los métodos `login` y `returning` solo necesitas especificar el `Widget` actual. Según la documentación para el método [QStackedWidget.setCurrentWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstackedwidget.html#setCurrentWidget), el `Widget` ya debe de estar contenido dentro del `QStackedWidget`, y esto lo hemos hecho en el método `__init__`:

  ```
  self.central_widget.addWidget(self.login_widget)
  self.central_widget.addWidget(self.search_widget)
  ```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda! A seguir con la app ahora.